# magento not working in server but working in localhost

Tags: php, magento

I have uploaded my Magento  project from local to server. In local it is working fine. But in server, I can access the home page only. If I try to access any product page , it will show 404 error. In the table core_config , I have change the unsecure/base_url and secure/base_url according to my new URL. But it still not working. Also I can log in to admin panel, but after login it is also show a 404 error. This is the url I get after login to admin http://demo.mysite.com/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/229f72cf1c46d9d723d7a34c1d525105/. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please check the database details in your local.xml file which is at app/etc/local.xml

Comment: I have checked that. It is fine and correct. Also I can see the Top menu (I have installed sample products) but when I click on any product or category , it will show the same 404.